# Add file in dist angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my angular project, I have :

```
- src (folder)

- maintenance (folder) 
   - maintenance.html
```

I want to add `maintenance.html` in `dist` folder

In angular.json , i have :

```
"sourceRoot": "src"
 .
 .
 .

"assets": [

     "src/favicon.ico",

     "src/assets",

     { "glob": "maintenance.html", "input": "../maintenance", "output": "./result" }


   ],
```

But I don't found the maintenance folder in Dist folder after running `npm run build`

Comment: Try changing `"output": "./result"` to `"output": "/"`

Comment: @HarunYilmaz it doesn't work

Comment: How about also changing to `"glob": "**/*"`. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/asset-configuration.md

Comment: And also try to add `/` after input value: `"input": "../maintenance/"`

Comment: I resolved the issue , my error was : "input": "../maintenance", it must be "input": "maintenance"

Comment: I didn't event noticed that :D Glad you solved :)

Comment: thank you all for your responses :D